# Complete a Mystery Sequence

Tags: code-golf, math, number

Given a sequence of three integers, determine if the sequence is arithmetic (of the form `[a, a+d, a+2*d]`) or geometric (of the form `[a, a*r, a*r^2]`) by outputting a fourth term that completes it (`a+3*d` for arithmetic, `a*r^3` for geometric).

Examples:

```
[1, 2, 3] -> 4 (This is an arithmetic sequence with a difference of 1)
[2, 4, 8] -> 16 (This is a geometric sequence with a ratio 2)
[20, 15, 10] -> 5 (arithmetic sequence, d=-5)
[6, 6, 6] -> 6 (arithmetic with d=0 OR geometric with r=1)
[3, -9, 27] -> -81 (geometric with r=-3)
```

- The input is guaranteed to be a valid arithmetic and/or geometric sequence (so you won't have to handle something like `[10, 4, 99]`)
- None of the inputted terms will be `0` (both `[2, 0, 0]` and `[1, 0, -1]` would not be given)
- For geometric sequences, the ratio between terms is guaranteed to be an integer (ie. `[4, 6, 9]` would be an invalid input, as the ratio would be 1.5)
- If a sequence could be either arithmetic or geometric, you may output either term that completes it
- You may take input as a 3-term array (or whatever equivalent) or as three separate inputs
- This is code golf, so aim for the lowest byte count possible!

Comment: I think I'll remove any test cases involving 0 (as a term). Someone on the sandbox mentioned [1, 0, 0]

Comment: Regarding *"If a sequence could be either arithmetic or geometric"*, this happens if and only if the three terms are equal, which corresponds to either (a = 0, d = 0, r = anything) or (a != 0, d = 0, r = 1).

Answer (score 18):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 34 bytes

#### -1 thanks to @Arnauld

```python
lambda a,b,c:c+(c-b)**2/(b-a or 1)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZBNTsMwEIXFtgdg_dSVU2xI0h9CpfQElZAQu9CFk9jUUhoH1wVxFjaVENwJTsPUClIRlcaLeXrzvRm_fXavfm3b_bvOHz52Xovsa9jITVlLSF7yal5dsEqU0WiUXrFSSFiHJOqdhaZuCdPCdqplcTQfwHCLHMvLbdcYz4ZiMYxIJEk9y4YZauxvY3tTVMQr0jtnWs80G5mI2z5i_312XiQcKcd4BbHABOx-bbagki2kM369Ud5U2KqnnWorhReSIFEbrZULitW08qAgxoQjC5hkdsTBo7IEcScoTnpjkR6mY45kSi8OgCnYiXCOOhdTcs84DhWssz_WAK7zGLd3R7lBdflhzTGHuKGLr8OwyBKwfz4x7v_nBw)

### How?

Uses the fact that the increments form a geometric sequence in either case. (This avoids the longish (in Python) ternary operator.)

Indeed:
\$c+\frac{(c-b)^2}{b-a} =
\begin{cases} c+(c-b)=2c-b & \text{if }c-b=b-a \\ c+(c-b)\times \frac c b = \frac{c^2} b & \text{if } \frac c b = \frac b a
\end{cases}\$

Comment: i accidentally downvoted can you edit so i can change it

Comment: Would it be OK to use `/` instead of `//`? Returning integers as floats is fine.

Comment: With "ternary operator" it's only 2 bytes longer: `lambda a,b,c:(c*b/a,c+b-a)[c-b==b-a]` (unfortunately cannot compress `c-b==b-a` into `c-2*b+a` because that can take values other than 0 or 1)

Comment: @Stef you could use `c*a<b*b`, though, couldn't you?

Answer (score 10):

## [Raku (Perl 6)](https://raku.org), 13 bytes

A block taking a sequence of length 3 as a single argument. This task is a perfect match for Raku's sequence operator.

```perl
{($_...*)[3]}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kKDG7dMGy3EoFlTTbpaUlaboWa6s1VOL19PS0NKONY2shYjd9rLmKEysVlFTiFXTtgGqBSjSVFNLyixQ0NAx1jHSMNXUUNIx0THQswAwDHUNTHUMDENtMBwhBDGMdXUsdI3NNTWuImQsWQGgA)

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 24 bytes

```python
lambda a,b,c:c*(a+c)/b-b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYzLDoIwEEX3fMXsaHGqVB4iSf0RdNEihCYFGi0av76WJjPJnJM71/7ctC6FH8XdGzmrpwSJCvu2z4g89PSkmPLfSZsBeJuAXizCujkLAmZpyfCRBne7OUKPb2u0IymwG6SUJmBfenFkJFkIUBAiflLfcYQzQvHYg2XShbtEaCLyOnCOwKuweVRV0tUI@0QMgQKBXUPHJQrW8D8)

Note that this fails when \$ a=0 \$ or \$ b=0 \$, but that seems to be OK for this challenge :). We can verify its correctness:

- For an arithmetic sequence \$ b-a = c-b \implies 2b = a+c \$, the formula rightfully produces \$ 2c-b \$:
  $$ \frac{c*(a+c)}{b}-b = \frac{c*2b}{b}-b = 2c-b $$
- Likewise, for a geometric sequence \$ b/a = c/b \implies a = b^2/c \$, the formula rightfully produces \$ c^2/b \$:
  $$ \frac{c*(a+c)}{b}-b = \frac{c*(b^2/c+c)}{b}-b = \frac{b^2+c^2}{b}-b = b+\frac{c^2}{b}-b = \frac{c^2}{b} $$

Comment: Since \$ 2b = a + c \$ and \$ b^2 = ac \$ respectively, you can just say \$ \frac { c ( a + c) } b - b = \frac { 2bc } b - b = 2c - b \$ and \$ \frac { c (a + c) } b - b = \frac { b^2 + c^2 } b - b = b + \frac { c^2 } b - b = \frac { c^2 } b \$.

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6), 28 bytes

```javascript
(a,b,c)=>c-2*b+a?c*c/b:2*c-b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7dDoIwDEbvfYpebrNjbPyIJuizbBWMhjADxtef5YbENe3VOd@XvvzXr7Q83x89x/uQxj4JjwFJ9lfSToWjv5EiEy5OkQ6J4rzGaSim@BCjsAgOoZISeIyB@vDPGdYI3c5tmwslgm34SnZYaDLeImy7F@T5CkGf@YnTZjDXnU0/)

#### Commented

```javascript
(a, b, c) =>    // given the 3 integers,
c - 2 * b + a ? // if the sequence is not arithmetic:
  c * c / b     //   assume it's geometric and return the next geometric term
:               // else:
  2 * c - b     //   return the next arithmetic term
```

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 28 bytes

```r
\(a,b,c)c+(c-b)^2/(b-a+!b-a)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZBBasMwEEXpNqf4IRuJjIhlx467cK9QKF2WgixLiRaJieLQw3TjFHqLnCSnqSJ1kdLASILPm6eRPk9-_LLN93Gwoj6_MUUtaa7nTIuWv-cL1go1n4aNJ-TyAMskIScUfAbxhCXY68YdEErtoLwbNlszOI2D2R_NTht8hAgKnbPW-Jj0FpJPLAuWJaFOIlndmLA2fdD4Ox6vBtcjj_0ZQZZhZUlRgt0ZgNA1orzyFeFaCa7-wFHeNRmeX27ujqlv4rAFQTyGl69Su6gl2D9SFL8fNY7p_AE)

Port of [@loopy walt's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269495/55372).

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 33 bytes

```r
\(a,b,c)`if`(c-b-b+a,c*c/b,c+c-b)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZBBbsIwEEXVLaf4iI0DYxETEsIivUIl1GUXOI4NXkCECeIwbNJKHIqepsbugqpIY1n-evM89uXT9V-mup46w8vb8INJqkkla2vWTPGa1xNJaqymPpz4cxLB7xcYJggzQpaMwF8xB3vf2iN8yT2ks912pzurcNSHk94rjbOPINFYY7QLSWsgkoFh3jInlFEkigcTNrr1GvfE42RnW8xCf0oQuV9pVORgTwYgNBXP73xBuFeEiz9wkDdVirfVw90hdVUYNiPwpX_5IrbzUoD9I3n2-1F9H_cf)

Straightforward approach.

Answer (score 5):

## Google Sheets, 34 bytes

```cpp
=IF(A3/A2=A2/A1,A3*A2/A1,A3+A2-A1)
```

The formula assumes the sequence is in `A1:A3`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 33 bytes

```
1,$0=$1-2*$2+$3?$2*$3/$1:$2+$3-$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYq5DYBQDMX6TPGKVwERObglxCzUDMD4nwi5sSXf79OaD7STrtExeubFkhzpx59KrwWBlMCETcLgM9xkQSEJ3RHrBw)

You could remove the `1,` at the start if you assume that the output will not be 0, saving 2 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
I+×÷Ɲ$}E?UḢ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/99T@/D0w9uPzVWpdbUPfbhj0f@HO/dZP2qYo6Brp/CoYa714XaggArXw91bjk5@uHMxRAYoAVR6dFLYsa5HTWsOtwOJyP//lZSUog11FIx0FIxjQdpNFDRCMjKLFYAoMU8hsSizJCM3tSQzWaE4tbA0NS85VaEcKKSQqJCSmZaWWgQWyU9TMNTkigaaYaKjYAE2xtAMyRyF9NR8oCFFWEwpSizJzFcwAuk20FEwNAViA7ABpgoaWCzXUUix1TUFqjbTUQAhsFIzFKVgg1NsDRT8g5DsBYsW2YKcaayjoGsJ9LE5WLOuhaGCBoY6XWNNYMAAAA)

A monadic link taking a list of three integers and returning an integer.

### Explanation

```
I           | Increments (differences between consecutive list members)
       E?   | If all equal then:
 +       U  | - Add the increments to the reversed input list
     $}  U  | Else, following as a monad applied to the reversed input list:
  ×         | - Multiply by:
   ÷Ɲ       |   - The result of dividing each pair of neighbouring list members
          Ḣ | Head
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3), 13 bytes

```
¯≈[Ṛ+|ᵃ÷Iᵃ×]t
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyIiLCIiLCLCr+KJiFvhuZorfOG1g8O3SeG1g8OXXXQiLCIiLCIiLCIzLjQuMSJd)

Port of [Nick Kennedy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42248/nick-kennedy)'s [Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269489/53748), sort of?

Comment: Updated with attribution since there are now two Jelly answers. Always best to link regardless in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

## [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 29 bytes

```
3&/O
?+\M@/!]!?-R.n$n?[?-.*~:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/99YTd@fy147xtdBXzFW0V43SC9PJc8@2l5XT6vO6v///0b/dU3@WwAA)

-4 bytes thanks to [Nitrodon](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/69059/nitrodon)!

Uses [loopy walt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/107561/loopy-walt)'s [solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269495/97729), go upvote them!

```
3&/M\                        Read 3 arguments a b c on the stack
     !]!                     Pop and write c then b on the tape
        ?-R                  Push b on the stack and calculate b-a
           .n$n              if b-a is 0, replace with 1
               ?[?           Push b and c on the stack
                  -.*        Calculate (c-b)^2
                     ~:      Calculate (c-b)*(c-b)/(b-a or 1)
                       ?+    Pop c and calculate c+(c-b)*(c-b)/(b-a or 1)
                         \O@ Output the result
```

Comment: [29 bytes](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/99YTd@fy147xtdBXzFW0V43SC9PJc8@2l5XT6vO6v///0b/Tf6bAQA) by using a different code layout.

Answer (score 2):

## APL+WIN, <s>43</s> 38 bytes

Prompts for integers

```
↑(=/¨a b)/(↑v×↑a←2÷/v),(↑v+↑b←2-/v←⌽⎕)
```

[Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcQJanP5BlyPWooz3t/6O2iRq2@odWJCokaeprAHllh6cDyUSgCqPD2/XLNHXAgtpAIgkkpqtfBqQe9ewFmqP5H2gE1/80LkMFIwVjrjQuIwUTBQsQbaBgaKpgaABkmikAIZA2Vji03lLByFwBAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Funge-98](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Funge-98), 46 bytes

```
<@.+wR-R:VI\OO-R:VIVI(4"FRTH"(4"STRN"
/\OR<@.*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//@3cdDTLg/SDbIK84zx9wfTYZ4aJkpuQSEeSkA6OCTIT4lLP8Y/CKhS6/9/Yy5dSy4jcy4A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

Uses the trick described by [loopy walt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/107561/loopy-walt) in their excellent [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269495/53748) although the implementation is somewhat different.

```
IQ²÷¥@/+Ṫ
```

A monadic Link that accepts a triple of integers, `[a, b, c]`, that is either arithmetic or geometric and yields the next integer in the series, `d`.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98z8NCmw9sPLXXQ1364c9X/o5Me7pyhc7g961HDHAVbO4VHDXM1I///j4421FEw0lEwjtXhUogGMkx0FCwgbAMdBUNTIDYAc810FEAIzDbWUdC1BGozB/JiAQ)**

#### How?

```
IQ²÷¥@/+Ṫ - Link: list of integers, [a, b, c]
I         - forward differences -> [b-a, c-b]
 Q        - deduplicate
             -> if arithmetic: L=[b-a] (potentially [0])
                else:          L=[b-a, c-b] (with no zeros)
      /   - reduce L by:
     @    -   with swapped arguments:
    ¥     -     last two links as a dyad - f(x, y):
  ²       -       square -> x^2
   ÷      -       divide -> x^2/y
             -> if arithmetic: Z=b-a (only one item so reduce does not perform f)
                else:          Z=(c-b)^2/(b-a)
       +  - add {[a, b, c]} (vectorises) -> [a+Z,b+Z,c+Z]
        Ṫ - tail -> c+Z (= d)
             -> if arithmetic: d=c+(b-a)
                else:          d=c+(c-b)^2/(b-a)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-2), 6 bytes

```
+∇/*⁰-
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyJBIiwiIiwiK+KIhy8q4oGwLSIsIiIsIjMsIDEsIDJcbjgsIDIsIDQiXQ==)

Port of [dingledooper's clever formula](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269517/100664), go look at that for an explanation of why this works.

```
       # input c, a, b
+      # c+a
 ∇     # rotate stack to b, c, c+a
  /    # c/b
   *   # (c+a) * c/b
    ⁰  # last input (b)
     - # (c+a) * c/b - b
```

This uses four necessary operations (`+/-*`) and two stack-manipulation operations (`⁰∇`). I'm fairly sure that a solution with only one stack-manipulation op is impossible but I'd love to be proven wrong.

Comment: Your explanation is incorrect. It's `c/b` not `b/c` (e.g. `(c+a) * b/c - b` for the first test case would be `(3+1) * 2/3 - 2 = ⅔` instead of `(3+1) * 3/2 - 2 = 4`). Your code and TIO are fine.

Answer (score 2):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 19 bytes

```
f(a,b,c)=c(a+c)/b-b
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/9zuaaxaunw)

Port of [dingledooper's Python 3 solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269517/96039), so make sure to upvote that one too!

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 24 bytes

```c
f(a,b,c){a=c*(a+c)/b-b;}
```

Another port of [dingledooper's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269495/120798)!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYzLCsIwEADv@YolYMjqBpPUJ0G/xMtmJaUHo1Rv4rfHUigzt4ER14u0VixTJsEvX2RteSO4zS6nX3vwUJdWnqNNb@FarF7dYVaTYTKZjODVp9c41M9cb1XTMkWcRgEidCrCDk4qegh7CF4dYEJ14M4Qj38)

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
+╠*k;,
```

Port of [*dingledooper*'s Python 3 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269517/52210), so make sure to upvote that answer as well!

I/O as floats, and inputs are in the order \$c,a,b\$.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/1/70dQFWtnWOv//G@sZKBgCsZGeAZcFhFYwAbINDUAcEGFoCuSaARlQzGVkDmSA9Ola6hkAAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
+       # Add the first two (implicit) inputs together: c+a
 ╠      # Divide it by the third (implicit) input: (c+a)/b
  *     # Multiply it by the first (implicit) input: (c+a)/b*c
   k;   # Push the second input, and discard it
     ,  # Subtract it by the third (implicit) input: (c+a)/b*c-b
        # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

The `k;,` could also be `?-Þ` for the same byte-count: [Try it online](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/1/70dQFWva6h@f9/2@sZ6BgCMRGegZcFhBawQTINjQAcUCEoSmQawZkQDGXkTmQAdKna6lnAAA).

```python
   ?    # Triple-swap the top three values: a,(c+a)/b,b
    -   # Subtract the top two: a,(c+a)/b-b
     Þ  # Only keep the top value of the stack: (c+a)/b-b
        # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 65 bytes

```
.+
$*
¶1+¶
$'$&
1(?=1*¶1+¶(1+))
$1
(?=1+¶(1+)¶)\1
1
(1+)¶\1¶1+

1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@qEZwQ46L9X0@bS0WL69A2Q@1D27hU1FXUuAw17G0NtSAiGobamppcKoZcIDEo/9A2zRhDLqAQmB1jCFLJxWX4/7@hjoKRjoIxF5Aw0VGw4DIy0FEwNAViAy4zHQUQ4jLWUbAEqjIHAA) Takes input on separate lines but link is to test suite that splits on non-digits for convenience. Limited to positive integers due to use of unary arithmetic. Explanation: Uses @dingledooper's formula.

```
.+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
¶1+¶
$'$&
```

Add `c` to `a`.

```
1(?=1*¶1+¶(1+))
$1
```

Multiply `a+c` by `c`.

```
(?=1+¶(1+)¶)\1
1
```

Divide that by `b`.

```
(1+)¶\1¶1+
```

Subtract `b` and remove `b` and `c`.

```
1
```

Convert to decimal.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 16 bytes

```
ＮθＮηＮζＩ⁻÷×⁺θζζηη
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98zr6C0xK80Nym1SKNQ05oLmZ@Bxq8C8gOKMvNKNJwTi0s0fDPzSos1PPNKXDLLMlNSNUIyc1OLNQJygIKFOgpVmhCcAcaamtb//xsr6FoqGJn/1y3LAQA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Trivial implementation of @dingledooper's formula.

35 bytes to validate the input:

```
ＮθＮηＮζ¿⁼⊗η⁺θζＩ⁻⁺ζηθ¿∧θ⁼×ηη×θζＩ÷×ζηθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYyxDoMgFEV3v@KNjwSTOjs1tYNDjUN/AIUGEsQi4ODPU6wMtuPJPfeMki3jzHSMrXkH34VpEAtaUhdnln@8JVYvwLsNTDts5jBowZNGodfBoaWwEUKgX5TxeGPO40OZNHzXjcJu2mTUhdBOwN66Gr7/cvKpJuFQHuYBOfpTbY1v1Kq4yIdzOsayggtUsVz1Bw) Link is to verbose version of code. Works with edge cases such as `0 0 0`, `1 0 0`, `1 0 -1`. Doesn't output anything if the input is not an arithmetic or geometric sequence.

Notes for both solutions:

- 6 bytes (`ＮθＮηＮζ`) could be saved by requiring the input to be in JSON format.
- Floating-point arithmetic could be used by replacing `÷` with `∕`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-ap`, 41 bytes

```perl
$_=2*($b=<>)-$_-($c=<>)?$c*$c/$b:$c+$b-$_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3tZIS0MlydbGTlNXJV5XQyUZxLRXSdZSSdZXSbJSSdZWSQLK/P9vxGXCZfYvv6AkMz@v@L@ur6megaHBf92CnEQA)